# Theano graph printing in Keras

Tags: python, theano, keras

Is there a way to print out the Theano graph representation of a Sequential model in Keras?

Given a simple model like this:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(input_dim=100,
                output_dim=50,
                W_regularizer=l2(0.0001),
                init='he_normal',
                activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(input_dim=50,
                output_dim=1,
                W_regularizer=l2(0.0001),
                init='he_normal',
                activation='sigmoid'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-7, momentum=.9)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I wish to run:

```
theano.printing.debugprint(model)
```

To give me something like this (taken from Theano tutorial):

```
Elemwise{mul,no_inplace} [id A] ''
 |TensorConstant{2.0} [id B]
 |x [id C]
```

I am hoping to get the graph to help understand the output of Theano profiler.

Keras version 1.0, Theano version 0.8.1.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else wants to do something similar, here is an approach I found out.

```
import theano
for i in model.layers:
    theano.printing.debugprint(i.input)
    theano.printing.debugprint(i.output)
```

It will give:

```
dense_input_2 [id A]
Elemwise{tanh,no_inplace} [id A] ''   
 |Elemwise{add,no_inplace} [id B] ''   
   |dot [id C] ''   
   | |dense_input_2 [id D]
   | |dense_4_W [id E]
   |DimShuffle{x,0} [id F] ''   
     |dense_4_b [id G]
Elemwise{tanh,no_inplace} [id A] ''   
 |Elemwise{add,no_inplace} [id B] ''   
   |dot [id C] ''   
   | |dense_input_2 [id D]
   | |dense_4_W [id E]
   |DimShuffle{x,0} [id F] ''   
     |dense_4_b [id G]
sigmoid [id A] ''   
 |Elemwise{add,no_inplace} [id B] ''   
   |dot [id C] ''   
   | |Elemwise{tanh,no_inplace} [id D] ''   
   | | |Elemwise{add,no_inplace} [id E] ''   
   | |   |dot [id F] ''   
   | |   | |dense_input_2 [id G]
   | |   | |dense_4_W [id H]
   | |   |DimShuffle{x,0} [id I] ''   
   | |     |dense_4_b [id J]
   | |dense_5_W [id K]
   |DimShuffle{x,0} [id L] ''   
     |dense_5_b [id M]
```